# Updating back of array without using push() in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to update the back of an array WITHOUT using the push() function, so I decided to use the splice() function and pass -1, and 0, and then the value so that it would update my array at the last index. I am then trying to return the length of the updated array, which should be 5.

```js
function push(array, value) {
  var upDatedArray = array.splice(-1, 0, value);
  var lengthArray = upDatedArray.length;
  return lengthArray;
}

console.log (
  push([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 6)
  );
```

What am I doing wrong here? Because it keeps returning 0, rather than the desired '5' length that I am looking for?

Comment: what is wanted result of the example?

Comment: @NinaScholz I want to add a value to the back of the array, and then return the new array and its new (updated) length. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Why not `push`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array.splice() returns an array with the deleted elements (in these case an empty array). splice given the array's length.

```js
function push(array, value) {
  array.splice(array.length, 0, value);
  return array.length;
}

let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log (
  push(a, 6)
  );
  
console.log(a)
```

Comment: Gotcha, did not realize that I needed to splice on the arrays length. Thank you for the help!!

Comment: No problem! I would prefer J Benda's solution above with the spread operator wrapped into a push function, you'll find that not mutating function parameters will save you a lot of trouble in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just try the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
var newArr = [...arr, 5];
console.log(newArr);
```

The answer to your question is that splice() does not return the updated array! So you should check for

```
array.length
```

But our code does not work as you want to, because you dont append the number at the end, you add it as the penultimate number.

Greetings!

Comment: I have only used the spread operator a couple of times, but it is really cool and I would of never thought to do this. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You could concat the value, wrapped in an array to prevent to flat `value` if the `value` is an array.

```js
function push(array, value) {
    return array.concat([value]);
}

console.log (push([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 6));
```